# SYSDBA Cannot Drop A User in Oracle 12.1.0.2

Tags: database, oracle, permissions

Newbie in Oracle. I had successfully installed Oracle DB on CentOS 6.8. I have created two databases:

1. orcl
2. AVDB

There are some users present in the 'AVDB' database. I wish to drop a user in the AVDB database. But I am getting insufficient privileges error even though I am connected as SYS AS SYSDBA user. I am even unable to create a user using sys user.

However, when I am connected to the same database as a different user (the one I am trying to drop which is `avuser`) I am able to create users.

```
[oracle@via7was ~]$ sqlplus sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Feb 2 14:13:16 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Advanced Analytics,
Oracle Database Vault and Real Application Testing options

SQL> drop user avuser cascade;
drop user avuser cascade
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

SQL> create user test1 identified by secret;
create user test1 identified by secret
                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

SQL> disconnect
Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Advanced Analytics,
Oracle Database Vault and Real Application Testing options
SQL> conn avuser
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> create user test1 identified by secret;

User created.
```

Comment: Oracle Database Vault restricts sysdba from performing certain actions. However, that really is all I know about Oracle Database Vault... I suspect Database Vault on that database may have a rule setup that prevents create/drop user for sysdba (though, this is just a guess). Try the Oracle Database Vault docs for 12c: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DVADM/dvintro.htm#DVADM001

Comment: This was the problem. I had to first disable the vault by logging as the owner of the database. Only then the user could be dropped. Wonderful stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> First, determine if the vault is active:

```
 SQL> SELECT PARAMETER, VALUE FROM V$OPTION WHERE PARAMETER = 'Oracle Database Vault';

        PARAMETER
        ----------------------------------------------------------------
        VALUE
        ----------------------------------------------------------------
        Oracle Database Vault
        TRUE
```

> Then connect as the database owner and disable the vault:

```
SQL> conn avuser
        Enter password:
        Connected.
        SQL> EXEC DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM.DISABLE_DV;

        PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

> Connect as SYSDBA and restart the database:

```
SQL> conn sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.
```

> Drop the user by connecting as SYSDBA:

```
SQL> conn sys as sysdba
    Enter password:
    Connected.
    SQL> drop user avuser cascade;
    drop user avuser cascade
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected
```

> If you get the above error, find out the active sessions of the user
>   being dropped and kill them:

```
SQL> SELECT s.sid, s.serial#, s.status, p.spid FROM v$session s, v$process p WHERE s.username = 'AVUSER' AND p.addr(+) = s.paddr;

               SID    SERIAL# STATUS   SPID
        ---------- ---------- -------- ------------------------
                17      48252 INACTIVE 45579

        SQL> ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '17,48252';

        System altered.

        SQL> drop user avuser cascade;

        User dropped.
```

> Note: It's always advisable to re-enable the vault for security
>   reasons after your activities are completed.

Comment: +1 I considered adding an answer instead of the comment, but since the answer would have been just a blind shot in the dark about a tech I know nothing about (except for a simple one line description), it seemed like a bad idea...